How does loop unrolling eliminate cyclic copies?
I am working on Exercise 6a from Chapter 8 of Engineering a Compiler (Cooper, Torczon) 3rd edition.
For the question, consider the following snippet of code that performs a 5-step stencil:
do 20 i = 2, n-1, 1
    t1 = A(i,1)
    t2 = A(i,2)
    do 10 j = 2, m-1, 1
        t3 = A(i,j+1)
        A(i,j) = 0.2 × (t1 + t2 + t3 + A(i-1,j) + A(i+1,j))
        t1 = t2
        t2 = t3
    10 continue
20 continue

The question posed is: Loop unrolling can eliminate the copy operations. What unroll factor is needed to eliminate all copy operations in this loop?
I identified the two copies to be the assignments of t1 and t2 that occur within the inner loop. I do not understand how unrolling would eliminate these copies. Let's say I unroll by a factor of 3, constant fold, rearrange the order of instructions and rename the variables. I end up with:
do 20 i = 2, n-1, 1
    t1 = A(i,1)
    t2 = A(i,2)
    do 10 j = 2, m-1, 3
        t3 = A(i,j+1)
        t4 = A(i,j+2)
        t5 = A(i,j+3)
        A(i,j) = 0.2 × (t1 + t2 + t3 + A(i-1,j) + A(i+1,j))
        A(i,j+1) = 0.2 × (t2 + t3 + t4 + A(i-1,j+1) + A(i+1,j+1))
        A(i,j+2) = 0.2 × (t3 + t4 + t5 + A(i-1,j+2) + A(i+1,j+2))
        t1 = t4
        t2 = t5
    10 continue
20 continue

While the number of copies per assignment to an entry in A has decreased (2 copies per 1 assignment ---> 2 copies per 3 assignments), they have not been eliminated. Have I have unrolled the loop incorrectly, or have I misidentified the two copies?
